# How to split tuples in all columns of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, tuples, tolist

The columns in my dataframe contain tuples and empty cells. The number of columns in the dataframe is dynamic and the columns have no lables.

```
          **0                1               2**
**0**    name,score,ID    name,score,ID      None
**1**    name,score,ID       None            None
**2**        None            None         name,score,ID
```

I want to split the tuples of all columns in separate columns, i.e:

```
      **Name0    Score0    ID0    Name1   Score1    ID1    Name2   Score2   ID2**
**0**    name    score     ID     name    score     ID      None    None    None
**1**    name    score     ID     None    None     None     None    None    None
**2**    None    None     None    None    None     None     name    score     ID
```

I found the following:

```
df1[['Name', 'Score', "ID"]] = pd.DataFrame(df1[0].tolist(), index=df1.index)
```

which works basically, however it just splits the first columns tuples into separate columns (--> df1[0]). I cant find how to apply this to all columns tuples.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: {
            0: None,
            1: None,
            2: None,
            3: ("bartenbach gmbh rinner strasse 14 aldrans", 96, 1050),
            4: (
                "ait austrian institute of technology gmbh giefinggasse 4 wien",
                70,
                537,
            ),
        },
        1: {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},
        2: {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},
    }
)

print(df)
# Outputs
                                                   0     1     2
0                                               None  None  None
1                                               None  None  None
2                                               None  None  None
3  (bartenbach gmbh rinner strasse 14 aldrans, 96...  None  None
4  (ait austrian institute of technology gmbh gie...  None  None
```

You could iterate on each column, then each value, split the string and populate a new dataframe, like this:

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for col_num, series in df.iteritems():
    for i, value in enumerate(series.values):
        try:
            name, score, id_num = value
            new_df.loc[i, f"Name{col_num}"] = name
            new_df.loc[i, f"Score{col_num}"] = score
            new_df.loc[i, f"ID{col_num}"] = id_num
        except TypeError:
            continue
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
# Outputs
                                               Name0  Score0     ID0
0          bartenbach gmbh rinner strasse 14 aldrans    96.0  1050.0
1  ait austrian institute of technology gmbh gief...    70.0   537.0
```

Comment: With me this results in an empty new_df. Without try-block it results in AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: You can run my code as it is and see that it works. You need the try/except statement to deal with empty cells. So, I suspect your real datraframe differs from the one you gave as an example in your question. What is the output of df.head().to_dict() ?

Comment: {0: {0: None,
  1: None,
  2: None,
  3: ('bartenbach gmbh rinner strasse 14 aldrans', 96, 1050),
  4: ('ait austrian institute of technology gmbh giefinggasse 4 wien',
   70,
   537)},
 1: {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},
 2: {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},
 3: {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},
 4: {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None}}

Comment: Based on these new specs, I've updated my answer, everything should run just fine now.